# existe alguna manera de tomar la informacion de una vista de una base de datos y pasarla a una nueva base de datos

Tags: sql-server, tablas, vistas

quiero saber si me pueden ayudar con esta duda, tengo una base de datos a la cual solo tengo acceso a la vistas quisiera saber si existe algún método que me permita tomar dicha información de las vista y insertarlas en una nueva base de datos que me permita manejar la información de las vistas y poder agregar mas campos columnas o tablas
gracias

Comment: Pues podrías hacer el select sobre la vista y llevarte el resultado a la otra base de datos que puedes manipular a tu antojo. Puedes extraer el resultado de la consulta sobre la vista como un csv y cargarlo en la otra BD, puedes hacer un linked server y con eso sólo hacer un insert into select,...

Comment: Por favor, edita la pregunta para limitarla a un problema específico con suficiente detalle para identificar una respuesta adecuada.